# Significance between odd ratios

Tags: r, logistic, odds

I´m fairly new to the tools of statistics and I need some help.
I´m working in R.
I have a list of students, their age, sex, test results(continuous variable) and education (a categorical variable. 0 if student has no education, 1 if student has education). This is stored in the data frame df.

I have assigned each student an age group depending on their age. The groups are 5-10,11-15, 16-20, 21-25. So now I have a new categorical variable with 4 levels.

I have done logistic regression for each age group. I did the test in R like this:

```
model1 = glm(education ~ test results + sex + age, data = df, family = binomial())
```

From the logistic regression result I compute the odds ratio (exp(coefficient)) for the test results variable. For each age group I got an odds ratio and confidence interval. There are some differences in the odds ratio between age groups. The odd ratio gets closer to 1 with higher age group. I interpret this in the following way; as the age of students is higher there is less effect from education on test result.
My question is how can I test if the difference in odds ratios is significant, i.e. what test can I use in R ?

Here is a subset of the data:

```
student sex age testScore education ageGroup

1        1   10   0.12       1        1

2        1    8   0.08       1        1

3        2   16   0.85       0        3

4        2   20   0.12       0        3

5        1   22   1.02       0        4

6        2   18   0.98       1        3

7        1   19   0.46       1        3

8        1   16   0.83       0        3

9        2   12   0.26       1        2

10       2   14   0.46       0        2
```

I have been searching books and the web without success, can´t seem to find an example that I can relate to.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to be careful with your interpretation. When you interpret a variable in a (logistic) regression model of the form Y ~ X1+X2+X3 all the interpretations of a variable's coefficients assume that the rest of the variables remain constant/stable. I don't get what "as the age of students is higher there is less effect from education on test result" exactly means. I think you should, first, focus on what exactly you want to investigate and then use a statistical model or a test to find out.

Comment: My interpretation of the odd ratio was just a thought on the side. What I want to investigate is the relation between the education and test score for each of the age groups. The odds ratios I get do tell you something. Its the question, are the odds ratios significantly different, I want answered.

Comment: Great. This is a very well formulated question. So, I think you don't need `sex` in the model and I guess you could investigate the interaction `education ~ test results:age`. But, the easiest and most straightforward approach in terms of interpretation is to do a logistic model of `education ~ test results` for each age group. If you have a sample of data, or if you can create some fake data, similar to the actual ones, I'll be able to help you more.

Comment: PS: Interpreting the coefficients/odds ratios of the independent variable `age` on the dependent variable `education` like you did above will tell you how `age` affects `education` when `test results` remain constant. This is not what you want to investigate here.

Comment: Added an example of the data

Comment: The `education` column? :-)

Comment: Do you know the answer now? How to compare the difference in odds ratios? I have the same problem, could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data you provided let's see what the model you described above does. Note that the sample of data is very small and I can't get any statistically significant coefficients, but I'll ignore that (in this case) when I try to interpret the model's output.

```
  dt = read.table(text = "student sex age testScore education ageGroup


                1        1   10   0.12       1        1

                2        1    8   0.08       1        1

                3        2   16   0.85       0        3

                4        2   20   0.12       0        3

                5        1   22   1.02       0        4

                6        2   18   0.98       1        3

                7        1   19   0.46       1        3

                8        1   16   0.83       0        3

                9        2   12   0.26       1        2

                10       2   14   0.46       0        2", header=T)

# create factor variables
dt$ageGroup = as.factor(dt$ageGroup)
dt$education = as.factor(dt$education)


summary(glm(education ~ testScore+sex+ageGroup, data = dt, family = binomial()))

# Coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept)   19.2260  4612.1501   0.004    0.997
# testScore      0.3885     2.9652   0.131    0.896
# sex           -0.6988     1.8748  -0.373    0.709
# ageGroup2    -17.9683  4612.1504  -0.004    0.997
# ageGroup3    -18.7778  4612.1502  -0.004    0.997
# ageGroup4    -37.4896  7988.5385  -0.005    0.996
```

You can see that `ageGroup1` is missing because it's the baseline for comparions with the other groups. So, you can interpret the output as "when `sex` and `testScore` remain the same, ageGroup1 is correlated with a higher probability of having `education = 1`, then it's ageGroup2, then 3 and 4". This is easy if you compare the coefficients. Eg. `-17.9683` is the difference between ageGroup 2 and 1, so 1 is better than 2.

However, this is not what you want. You said "investigate the relation between the education and test score for each of the age groups". To put that in a more statistical perspective, or in terms of how the model understands that investigation, this is the same as "within each age group is there evidence of a true (statistically significant) relationship between `testScore` and `education`? Is it positive or negative?" The easiest way is to create a model for each `ageGroup`. As an example I'm considering `ageGroup` 3.

```
summary(glm(education ~ testScore, data = dt[dt$ageGroup==3,], family = binomial()))

# Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept)   -1.246      2.294  -0.543    0.587
# testScore      1.268      3.085   0.411    0.681
```

So, within that group `testScore` is positively correlated with the probability of having `education = 1`. For 1 unit increase in `testScore` the odds of having `education = 1` increase by 255% {As exp(1.268) = 3.55}.

Let me know if you have more questions and I can update my answer to be more clear. I'd suggest you spend some time on interpreting logistic regression coefficients of a continuous, or categorical, variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is very clear and I have learned a lot from it. OK. So I create a model for each age group as you did. Let´s say that the odds increase as I go from age group 1 to 4. How would I test if those odds are significantly different ?

Comment: Each time you create a model you're within an age group. So, that model doesn't know/care that there are other age groups. In other words you can't compare age groups but test scores. So, you will be able to say if the odds increase for a 1 unit increase of `testScore`. And that could be found by checking the p value of that coefficient in column `Pr(>|z|)`. When you say "from age group 1 to 4" that contradicts your objective that said "relation between the education and test score for each of the age groups". Is it possible that you want something else?